# bash + Compare Strings with regex

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, regular-expression

in my bash script I want to verify if string is a disk

so I did the following example

```
if [[ $disk =~ sd{a..z} ]];then
echo "we found a disk - $disk
.
.
.
.
fi
```

but actually the expression not identify the $disk ( $disk could be for example sda sdb sdc sdd etc )

for example

```
disk=sdb
[[ $disk =~ sd{a..z} ]] && echo "$disk is real disk"
```

also not as

```
[[ $disk =~ 'sd{a..z}' ]]
```

where I am wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=~` is a binary operator, from the manual [3.2.5.2 Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html):

> An additional binary operator, ‘=~’, is available, with the same
> precedence as ‘==’ and ‘!=’. When it is used, the string to the right
> of the operator **is considered a POSIX extended regular expression**[...]

`{a..z}` is a brace expansion 3.5.1 [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

> Brace expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary strings may be
> generated.

---

So you need a *regex* pattern to match the string:

```bsh
$ disk=sdb    
$ [[ $disk =~ ^sd[a-z]$ ]] && echo "$disk is real disk"
$ sdb is real disk
```

Comment: Or use the simpler and more portable (from ksh88) `[[ $disk = sd[a-z] ]]` or the even more portable (standard sh) `case $disk in (sd[a-z])...`. Beware that in `zsh`, if the `rematchpcre` option is enabled `[[ $disk =~ ^sd[a-z]$ ]]` could also match on `$'sda\n'`. With PCRE, you need `\z` to match at the end of the subject. Whether `[a-z]` matches on `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` only or not will also depend on the operator, system, shell, shell version and locale.